# DBI convert fetched arrayref to hash

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I'm trying to write a program to fetch a big MySQL table, rename some fields and write it to JSON. Here is what I have for now:

```
use strict;

use JSON;
use DBI;

# here goes some statement preparations and db initialization

my $rowcache;
my $max_rows       = 1000;
my $LIMIT_PER_FILE = 100000;

while ( my $res = shift( @$rowcache )
    || shift( @{ $rowcache = $sth->fetchall_arrayref( undef, $max_rows ) } ) ) {

    if ( $cnt % $LIMIT_PER_FILE == 0 ) {

        if ( $f ) {
            print "CLOSE $fname\n";
            close $f;
        }

        $filenum++;
        $fname = "$BASEDIR/export-$filenum.json";

        print "OPEN $fname\n";
        open $f, ">$fname";
    }

    $res->{some_field} = $res->{another_field}
    delete $res->{another_field}

    print $f $json->encode( $res ) . "\n";

    $cnt++;
}
```

I used the database row caching technique from
[*Speeding up the DBI*](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=273952)
and everything seems good.

The only problem I have for now is that on `$res->{some_field} = $res->{another_field}`, the row interpreter complains and says that `$res` is `Not a HASH reference`.

Please could anybody point me to my mistakes?

Comment: You could use **mysql-shell-output-formats** to get the output in `json` format directly [JSON Format Output](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-shell-output-formats.html)

Comment: Or use this [DBIx::JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~yosty/DBIx-JSON-0.02/lib/DBIx/JSON.pm#get_json)

Comment: @martinclayton, I understand this, but it seems `fetchall_hashref` doesn't  have any signature containing number of rows for batch processing. Correct me, please, if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AbhiNickz, It is really huge database table over 200 million entries. Does it provide any possibility to decompose data in chunks? Moreover I need to make some processing after the fetch (rename, etc)...

Comment: Instead of passing in undef for the first parameter, pass an empty hash reference, then you should get a ref to an array of hash refs back. i.e. fetchall_arrayref({}, $max_rows).  The docs for fetchall_arrayref say that if the first parameter is undefined, you will get an array of array refs.

Comment: Note that `fetchall_arrayref` is *slower* than `fetchrow_arrayref` when more than a few columns are involved. You would probably be better of using a simple `while ( my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) { ... }`. In any case you should not try to optimise your code until it is finished and complete and you have found it to be too slow, and even then you should *profile* your code to see where the bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want [`fetchall_arrayref`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchall_arrayref) to return an array of hashrefs, the first parameter should be a hashref. Otherwise, an array of arrayrefs is returned resulting in the "Not a HASH reference" error. So in order to return full rows as hashref, simply pass an empty hash:

```
$rowcache = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({}, $max_rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but for now it says `Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference` for some reason... Did I missed something?

Comment: Just a guess: It seems `rowcache` should be initialized to some value?

Comment: @mr.nothing Try to initialize the rowcache with `my $rowcache = [];`.

Comment: unfortunately, no luck. Will try to investigate it further.

Comment: @mr.nothing Initializing it with `[]` should do the trick. In what line do you get that error? Maybe it's not related and occurs in code you have not shown us.

Comment: ah, looked at the doc @nwellnhof provided and there is a tiny thing at the end of the line
`while( my $row = ( shift(@$rows) || shift(@{$rows=$sth->fetchall_arrayref(undef,10_000) !!! ||[] !!! }) ))` That do the trick after all. Thanks once again!

Comment: @nwellnhof: Using an undefined scalar as an array reference will autovifify an empty anonymous array and set the scalar to refer to it. No error will be raised. The problem is that `fetchall_arrayref` is returning `undef` when it reaches the end of the table